# How to deduce a return type in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

I want to create some kind of `Variant` in C++. Actually I want to use templates as less as possible. The idea is to store the value in `union` both with the type of the variable and return the value according to the stored type.

So the test code looks like following:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <typeindex>

using namespace std;

constexpr uint64_t mix(char m, uint64_t s)
{
    return ((s << 7) + ~(s >> 3)) + static_cast<uint64_t>(~m);
}

constexpr uint64_t _(const char* str)
{
    return (*str) ? mix(*str,_(str + 1)) : 0;
}

class Variant
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    Variant(T value):
        m_info(typeid(value))
    {
        std::memcpy(&m_val, &value, sizeof(T));
    }

    auto toValue() ->decltype(???) // what have I use here ???
    {
        switch(_(m_info.name()))
        {
            case _("b"):
                return m_val.bval;
            case _("i"):
                return m_val.ival;
            case _("d"):
                return m_val.dval;
            break;
        }

        return 0;
    }
    char cval;
    unsigned char ucval;

private:
    union Types
    {
        bool bval;
        int ival;
        double dval;
    } m_val;
    std::type_index m_info;
};
```

Usage:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::vector<Variant> arr = { 1, 2.2, true };
    for(auto &v: arr)
    {
        cout << "value is: " << v.toValue() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But `decltype` requires an expression as a parameter and that's where I'm stuck. What expression have I use here?

Comment: You are apparently trying to have a function whose return type gets deduced at runtime - this is not possible. The return type has to be known at compile time

Comment: Unfortunately, C++ does not work this way. The types of all objects -- this includes function return types -- must be known at compile time, not runtime. This is fundamental to C++, and there are no type-safe workarounds for this.

Comment: `typeinfo.name()` is not portable afaik

Comment: Type inference on return types is not supported in C++. Your best bet might be to write separate `toBool`, `toInt`, `toDouble`, or a single `template<typename T> T to()` specialized for each type, which would let you write `v.to<int>()`.

Comment: just a reminder, there is already `std::variant` and `std::any`, in case you start want to doing it yourself.

Comment: C++17 uses `std::visit` to solve this problem with `std::variant`.  That uses the visitor pattern to solve this issue.

Comment: The issue you are creating is larger than the code you propose here.  If this question were answered and you **were able** to get `auto x = v.toValue();` to compile, what would you then be able to do with `x`?  Could you expect `!!x` to be the same as `x`?  Could you express `x % 2`?  You couldn't, because the compiler no longer knows what type `x` is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per @UnholySheep's comment, what you're trying to do is have a function whose return type is deduced at runtime, which is simply not possible. The return type has to be known at compile time. So you're going to have to change your API. There are a few different options here.

This seems similar to [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), whose API equivalent to your `toValue()` looks like this:

```
std::get<double>(variant)
std::get<int>(variant)
std::get<bool>(variant)
```

This function call `std::get` will throw [`std::bad_variant_access`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/bad_variant_access) if you try to get the value with the wrong type. You could do that here.

Another option is to extract the `union { bool, int, double }` type out of the `Variant` class so you can use it as the return type. Then it'd probably be advisable to have another function call so the caller can tell at runtime which type the union actually is. You could return an enum or just return your `m_type` variable for this.

Comment: Yes, this is basically the same decision that I came to. Just one thought kept bothering me. I know the stored type and I could return the corresponding value ...

Comment: It doesn't matter, though, because the caller doesn't know the stored type when they call `toValue`. So they'd have to call `getType` or whatever anyway. This is the same with `std::variant`, since you have to call `std::holds_alternative<T>` to check what the type is before you can safely call `std::get<T>`.